# Getting id of element that opened a modal and load appropriate file with php/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have something like that

```html
<div class="overlay" >
  <a id="myId" class="info" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#InfoModal">More Info</a>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="InfoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
         aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        ×</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">More Info</h4></a></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <h4>More Inof<br></h4>
                        <img src="">
                        <p id="info" style="text-align: justify;">
                           
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
</div>
```

***Edit**

When "myId" is pressed I want the modal to open.

At the image element, I want it to load an image, for which the path will be created generically from the id of the anchor element pressed.

For example, in this case,  want the source of the image to be "src=myId.jpg".

Correspondingly I want some text to be loaded into the paragraph element from a file name "myId.txt"

I tried something like this, but obviously did not work (I understand why it does not), but that's what I want.

```js
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();

    j('.infoModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var id = e.relatedTarget.id;
        var myvar = <?php
            $homepage = file_get_contents(id);
            echo json_encode($homepage);
            ?>;
        j("#result3").html(myvar);
    })
```

Comment: what do you want to do exactly? please explain a little more.

Comment: `Any ideas` - you'll need some code, not just HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the modal using a click event and pass the data attribute

```
$('#myId').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var url = 'url of html template';

    $('#myModal').load(url, {'id': id}, function(e){
        $('#myModal').modal({
          target: "#myModal",
          toggle: 'modal'
        });
    });
});
```